# Create difference TIFF image from two TIFFs

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, numpy

I am trying to use gdal_calc to calculate the differences between two almost identical images. The problem is that the images are TIFFs with three bands (RGB) and the result is difficult to interpret. I use `--calc` but I don't really understand the syntax to get a mas(?) with only the differences.

I used this expression:

```
 --calc=(A-B) -> get a gray image
```

I would like to have White in the diferences and NoData in the equal values but I can't use "!=", for example:

```
--calc=((A-B)!=0) --calc=255*((A-B)==0) --NoDataValue=0
```

Comment: mas(?) -> mask.